# Spring Cloud embedded netty server with security vulnerabilities

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I'm using `spring-cloud-starter-gateway` and `spring-boot-starter-webflux` from [`spring-cloud-dependencies:2020.0.4`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/2020.0.4), packing everything in a docker image.

All my routes are written with `RouteLocatorBuilder` from spring cloud.

Scanning the image with [Grype](https://github.com/anchore/grype), I get the following vulnerabilites:
[image]

Latest [`reactor-netty-http:1.0.13`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor.netty/reactor-netty/1.0.13) still doesn't have these fixed.

I'd like to resolve these issues. Any suggestions?

**[UPDATE]**

Wrote to [Grype's Github](https://github.com/anchore/grype/issues/431#issuecomment-966202391) for further investigation. It does seem these are false positives, as Andreas mentioned below. Enforcing latest `netty` in my BOM for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose these are false positives as `reactor-netty-http` did not had the vulnerability it was `HttpObjectDecoder.java in Netty before 4.1.44`. The regex provided by https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-20444 are sometimes too unspecific.

According to the docs you can suppress the false positives following this guide: https://github.com/anchore/grype#specifying-matches-to-ignore

If you are using `maven` you could just add (but you don't have to because these are false positives):

```
    <project>
      ...
      <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.70.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </dependencyManagement>
      ...
    </project>
```

And the fixes are in `reactor-netty-http:1.0.13` as `netty 4.1.70` does not have any commonly known security flaws:

[image: POM Screenshot..]